# Report Builder: How to create a filter expression on a date hierarchy for all dates before last week?

Tags: ssas, reporting-services, mdx, reportbuilder3.0

Using `Report Builder 3.0` connected to a `TFS 2012` analysis database, need to create a filter on a date hierarchy, to match all days older than 14 days ago (specifically for the Created Date hierarchy of the Work Item dimension).

I'm guessing I need to set the operator to MDX and type in something a `DATEADD` expression somewhere, but I can't figure out how to get the syntax right.

I've tried:

```
[Date].[Date].membervalue <= DATEADD("d",-14,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember)
```

in the Filter Expression box, but it complains that the `CURRENTMEMBER` function expects a hierarchy expression and a member expression was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to do the filter in the dataset, I got everything in the dataset and created the filter as part of the report (under Datasets, Dataset properties, Filters, and then I was able to use the DateAdd and Now functions to get what I needed.